# Why does my allocated memory keep increasing when switching activities?

Tags: java, android

I had a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError occurring in my app when I got to my third activity in my android app.  I used the Android Monitor to examine my memory usage during the operation of my app, and from the first screen it was using 200mb with not a lot to spare.  The second activity used about 250.  I would go to my third activity, and click a button on the screen at the app would crash.

I removed the background images of my three activities and the app runs for a longer time.  But each time I switch between my third activity and my second activity (using intents), the allocated memory keeps increasing until the app eventually crashes (simply from switching between activities).

Does any of this give you a clue as to what is going on with my app?

Here's some code for my first activity along with its xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.norsemeadgames.tobiasandthegiant.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_back">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_items" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Resume"
        android:id="@+id/buttonResume"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_items"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now the Main Activity java file

```
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.Window;
     import android.view.WindowManager;
     import android.view.animation.Animation;
     import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
     import android.widget.Button;


     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements            View.OnClickListener {

    Button buttonStart;
    Button buttonResume;
    Button buttonQuit;
    Animation wobble;
    Player player;



    Monster bill = new Monster(Monster.randMonsterName(), 10, 200);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //makes activity run in fullscreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wobble = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.wobble);

        buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonResume = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonResume);


        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonResume.setOnClickListener(this);





    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        player = new Player();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v)  {
           switch (v.getId()){
               case R.id.buttonStart:
                   buttonStart.startAnimation(wobble);
                   wobble.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CityRendActivity.class);
                           intent.putExtra("player", player);
                           startActivity(intent);
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                       }
                   });

                   break;
           }
    }
    }
```

Here's City Rend java file

```
public class CityRendActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    int storyPage = 1;
    TextView storyWindow;
    TextView stats;
    Player player;


    ImageButton buttonMonsters;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //makes activity run in fullscreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_city_rend);

        storyWindow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStoryWindow);
        storyWindow.setText(GameElements.fillStoryWindow(1));
        storyWindow.setOnClickListener(this);

        stats =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStats);
        buttonMonsters = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonMonsters);
        buttonMonsters.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();


        Player player = (Player)intent.getSerializableExtra("player");

        stats.setText("HP = " + player.getHealth() + "  |  Str = " + player.getStrength() + "  |  Gold = " +
                player.getGP() + "  |  Wpn = " + player.getWeapon());

        this.player = player;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.textStoryWindow:
                if(storyPage == 0){
                    storyPage = 1;
                }
                if(storyPage == 1){
                    storyPage = 2;
                }else if(storyPage == 2){
                    storyPage = 3;
                }else if(storyPage == 3) {
                    storyPage = 1;
                }
                storyWindow.setText(GameElements.fillStoryWindow(storyPage));
                break;
            case R.id.buttonMonsters:
                Intent intent = new Intent(CityRendActivity.this, MonstersActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("player", player);
                startActivity(intent);

    }
    }


}
```

Now the Monsters activity java file

```
public class MonstersActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Player player;
    Button buttonBack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //makes activity run in fullscreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monsters);

        buttonBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);

        buttonBack.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Player intentPlayer = (Player)intent.getSerializableExtra("player");
        player = intentPlayer;

        player.setHealth(10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MonstersActivity.this, CityRendActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("player", player);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: 200mb is a lot! You should post the code of your activities otherwise noone can help you.

Comment: do you really switch between activities (i.e. finish the old one) or do you put a new instance onto the activity stack each time?

Comment: It looks like you are doing some `Heavy operation on UiThread`, you need to do heavy load from outside the main thread

Comment: @MustansarSaeed  I'm still new when it comes to understanding Threading.  Could you elaborate on a solution I should try or suggest a good article that could help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It can also happen if you are loading images of huge sizes. Check this link -> http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @MichaelArnold Please also post `CityRendActivity` code

Comment: @ParagKadam I removed the main images when I was trying to narrow down the problem and I could still make the program crash fairly quickly.

Comment: You should create a `Player` object only when you need one, not every time the activity resumes.

Comment: @MustansarSaeed I uploaded it now.  Thanks for taking the time to read it.

Comment: @MichaelArnold Post the third Activity also